# Transparent container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, transparent

I'm a beginner in flutter and trying to make a transparent container in Flutter. It should be 100% transparent with the background. I tried using **Colors.transparent** as *color* property of *container* but it's not what i want.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widget. Add your container instead of MyTransparentWidget() in this example, that's it.

```
 Opacity(
            opacity: 0,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: <YOUR WIDGET>,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this makes it completely invisible. I want something like the **Appbar** shown in the _image_ provided in the _link_. Its border should be visible but should look like a hollow container.

Comment: i've updated the answer please check. this will work for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but without giving any color property to container you're making it already a transparent one. No need to use opacity widget.

Comment: @ShivamSingh you can set property to "backgroundColor: Colors.transparent"